# Forum bundle - Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any forum bundle for Symfony 3? I've been looking for several hours in the Internet, but haven't found anything. Some of forum bundles are for Symfony 2.x and seem to be dead for years. I know, there is a PhpBB, which is based on Symfony but there is a lack of information about integration PhpBB users with FOSUserBundle (such Vanilla has). If you know some forum bundle (even the simplest) please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I don't think that deserves a down vote though?

Comment: True. Deserves to be closed.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [this](https://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNForumForumBundle) and I think is good, even is unsupported. [Here](http://knpbundles.com/keyword/forum) you can find a lot of module related to blogs.

This is another one: https://packagist.org/packages/herzult/forum-bundle

Comment: I saw those, unfortunately CCDNForumForumBundle is for Symfony 2.4 (and no longer supported) and HerzultForumBundle hasn't been developed for 4-5 years. I think I write something simple by myself...